# Lowest Common ancestor in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Its pretty easy to find closest common ancestor in a BST if all the elements are distinct. But what if some of the values are same. Till now we were just comparing the data of nodes and that was it, but now do we need to check for nodes' address instead of just values?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, instead of using just your `key` for the comparison, use `(key, address of node)` for comparison. This simplifies the code when dealing with non-unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what kind of struct you are using, it's hard to give specifics, but you could try something like this pseudocode:

```
struct BST {
    struct BST* parent;
    struct BST* left;
    struct BST* right;
    void* value;
}

find_common_ancestor(struct BST* x, struct BST* y)
{
    set<struct BST*> ancestors;

    // Add all of x's ancestors to set.
    while (true) {
        ancestors.insert(x);

        if (x == NULL)
            break;

        x = x=>parent;
    }

    // Check y's ancestors against x's until a match is found.
    while (true) {
        if (ancestors.count(y) > 0)
            return y;

        y = y->parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ swiss: u r not given a parent field for any node. If the parent node were given then what will be the use of BST. :P

Comment: @arvind mohan: There is nothing stopping a BST implementation from having a pointer to its parent. True, it's technically not needed, but it does make certain things easier - like what you are trying to do. Even if you aren't given the parent pointer, you can walk the tree to create a set containing x's and y's ancestors; you can use that in the while loops instead of the parent pointer.

Answer (score 0):

here is psudocode. just convert them into syntax.

```
GETLeastCommonAn(BINARYTREE BT, NODE A, NODE  B)
IF Root==NIL
    return NIL
ENDIF

IF Root==A OR root==B
    return Root
ENDIF

Left = GETLCA (Root.Left, A, B)
Right = GETLCA (Root.Right, A, B)

IF Left! = NIL AND Right! = NIL
    return root
ELSEIF Left! = NIL
    Return Left
ELSE
    Return Right
ENDIF
```